# How to display values from Controller to Blade file in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

From Controller:

```
    $response = (new ApiController)->checkNumbers();
    if(!empty($response['status']) && ($response['status'] == 'SUCCESS')) {
                $numbers = json_encode($response['numbers']);
    }
    return [
              'html' => view('show.numbers', compact(
                        'numbers'
                    ))->render()
                ];
```

How I can show "numbers" in blade file to reflect on UI in table ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: If your `if()` statement doesn't pass, `$numbers` is not defined, and `compact('numbers')` will fail. Beyond that, `{{ $numbers }}` is how you print it in a View. Please read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade

Comment: And where 'list' came from?

Comment: If you want to see what information the blade is receiving, in the blade file, add a `@php dd($__data); @endphp` at the top to see the info.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example on how you can pass data from your controller and populate it to your blade.

For example I have a table: 'user' with columns id,firstname and lastname:

SampleController.php

```
public function FetchUser(){
    $data = User::all();
    
    return view('MyView')->with([
     'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```

MyView.blade.php

```
{{-- populate it in a table --}}
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
@foreach($data as $item){
    <tr>
      <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
      <td>{{$item->firstname}}</td>
      <td>{{$item->lastname}}</td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```